# Can I turn the (unevaluated) argument of a python function into a string?

Tags: python, pytest

Is it possible to have a function in Python where `fun(1+1)` arrives in the function as `'1+1'` rather than `2`?

Common sense would say it can't be done, because there is no way to keep the `1+1` from being evaluated before it is passed to the function.
But the same common sense would say, that the following PHP code should not work, because `unset($arr[0])` should be the same as `unset(99)`. But it works - and the latter is a syntax error.

```php
$arr = [99, 1, 2, 3, 99];
unset($arr[0]);  # remove the first element
$arr = array_values($arr);  # reindex from 0
echo $arr == [1, 2, 3, 99];  # yes
```

So maybe Python also has a loophole for this kind of weirdness.

I would like to use that to write shorter tests. Currently I have:

```python
with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
    1/0
with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
    0/0
with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
    0**-1

with pytest.raises(FooError):
    Foo(round_hole=SquarePeg)
with pytest.raises(FooError):
    Foo(give_me_five=6)
```

Instead I would rather write:

```python
shorter(ZeroDivisionError, [1/0, 0/0, 0**-1])

shorter(FooError, [
    Foo(round_hole=SquarePeg),
    Foo(give_me_five=6)
])
```

I could of course pass strings - but the disadvantage of lost syntax highlighting would eat up the advantage of brevity.

**Edit 1:** It might not be a terrible idea to "open" a test file from test mode to write mode by making string replacements like
`',  # expr\n    '` to `'",  # expr\n    "'`.

```python
# write mode
shorter(FooError, [  # except
    Foo(round_hole=SquarePeg),  # expr
    Foo(give_me_five=6)  # expr
])

# test mode
shorter(FooError, [  # except
    "Foo(round_hole=SquarePeg)",  # expr
    "Foo(give_me_five=6)"  # expr
])
```

**Edit 2:** Actually, the lambda approach proposed by hoefling works fine. It is generally the case, that missing arguments raise an error right in the test file. The way to avoid it is to use `__init__(self, arg=None)` instead of just `__init__(self, arg)`.

Definition of `shorter` and example classes:

```python
import pytest
from inspect import isclass


def shorter(expected, values):
    if isclass(expected) and issubclass(expected, Exception):
        for value in values:
            with pytest.raises(expected):
                value()
    else:
        for value in values:
            assert value == expected


class Hand():
    def __init__(self, give_me_five=None):
        if give_me_five is None:
            raise NoArgError
        if give_me_five != 5:
            raise NotFiveError
        self.twice_five = 2 * give_me_five


class NoArgError(ValueError):
    """You need to provide and argument."""


class NotFiveError(ValueError):
    """The argument must be 5."""
```

Example test file:

```python
from .other_file import shorter, Hand, NoArgError, NotFiveError


def test_errors():
    check(NoArgError, [
        lambda: Hand()
    ])
    check(NotFiveError, [
        lambda: Hand(0),
        lambda: Hand(6),
        lambda: Hand(''),
        lambda: Hand('5')
    ])


def test_values():
    check(10, [
        Hand(5).twice_five
    ])
```

Comment: You can pass `lambda: 1/0`, `lambda: 0/0` etc as arguments and call e.g. `with pytest.raises(Error): fn()` in the test.

Comment: That indeed works for `lambda: 1/0`, but when I pass `lambda: Foo()` where `Foo` requires an argument, it will raise the error right there.

Comment: Then pass `lambda *args, **kwargs: Foo(*args, **kwargs)` and `with raises(...): fn(foo="bar")`

Comment: The arguments like `give_me_five=6` should be written in the test file. Your proposal looks like you would write them in the place where `shorter` is defined. Anyway, I begin to suspect that the answer to my question is *no*.

Comment: Not without some very ugly reflection and stack walking I suspect. I would also caution that this is a very bad idea.

Comment: [You really shouldn't try to use PHP to make points about common sense.](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)

Comment: Also `lambda: Foo()` does not raise an argument immediately, and you want `lambda: Foo(round_hole=SquarePeg)` anyway.

Comment: @hoefling Your lambda approach actually worked. See Edit 2 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. This isn't R; function arguments are evaluated before the function has a chance to do anything at all.

You should just use the [non-context-manager form](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions) of `pytest.raises`:

```
pytest.raises(FooError, Foo, round_hole=SquarePeg)

pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError, lambda: 1/0)
```

This asserts that the provided callable raises the provided exception when called with the provided arguments.